# Kivy not being imported despite installlation

Tags: python, kivy

I just installed kivy on python 3.5.0. However, every time I try to import kivy; it shows the error "No module named Kivy".
I am very new to all this so step by step instructions would be helpful.

Comment: A bit more background is needed here. What is your setup: do you have multiple python versions installed? How did you install kivy? Also it might just be a small capitalization error: in your error message it says "no module named **K**ivy (capital K)", but you need to `import kivy`(lowercase k)

Comment: Execute `pip freeze` to see if kivy is really there?

Comment: Which operating machine are you working on? 1. You should import kivy with a lowercase k. 2. If that doesn't working, you may need to MAKE SURE its been installed for the Python version you are using. In windows something such as "py -3.5 -m pip install kivy" should work.

Comment: No i only have Python 3.5.0;

Comment: I had imported using lowercase k only

Comment: I installed kivy using command prompt...just as Simeon Ikudabo said.. the same instructions are elaborated on the kivy official website...which i followed properly

Answer (score 0):

Many operating systems come with python 2.7 and 3.5 already installed. I know you said you have 3.5, but check this anyway with `python2 -V`. In the comments,you said that you have been importing kivy correctly into your files. It may be that you are accidentally running your python3 app with python2.

Kivy for python2 is not the same as kivy for python3. If you want to be sure that you're running with the python version you want, run your app with `python3 filename.py`.

If all this is said and done, and you still don't find out what's wrong, you either installed kivy for python2 somehow or it's searching for kivy in the wrong place.